# JAXB - Solution and strategies for "collision in the object factory class"

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a set of xsd files and I need to generate java classes for these types. The problem is with multiple xsd files and multiple definitions of xml types in these files. And the multiple definitions are not all straight forward. Some over-ride the definition, some extend and some are the same with different namespaces and others are the same in all sense. There is no regular pattern(Actually these XSDs are from a different company and they need the data in xml - so they don't care about the JAVA-XML mapping and so complaining about XSDs is not really an option :|).

I tried two different JAXB plugins(mojo and jvnet) and both of them give the same error -

> com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.

I understand that this is bound to happen and tried a couple of things. Using mojo plugin, I tried to tell maven to compile all files seperately and put them in different packages (multiple  in the plugin, each with its own  and separate ), but to no avail.

And later I tried to do the same thing in another way. I used the jvnet plugin and defined the mapping of xsd and java package in the bindings.xml file as follows -

```
    <bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/1.0/abcd.xsd">
      <schemaBindings>
        <package name="com.xxx.services.yyy.abcd"/>
      </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>
```

And then I encountered this error -

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Multiple <schemaBindings> are defined for the target namespace "http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping"
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ErrorReporter.error(ErrorReporter.java:79)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.checkMultipleSchemaBindings(BGMBuilder.java:343)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.buildContents(BGMBuilder.java:313)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder._build(BGMBuilder.java:182)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:116)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:415)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.loadModel(RawXJC2Mojo.java:636)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:259)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:135)
```

which is the same error presented in a different way.

Now before diving into other options, I decided to find out the best strategy I should be using for this type of binding. Apparently the one I know isn't working. Any suggestions anyone? And what can be a solution for this problem?

help much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question so that anyone searching can find it useful. The basic point to understand is that there is no way to compile all the files seperately and then group them into java packages(If there are elements that need to go to same java packages). So, the only way left is to isolate all the types that are causing the problem (as I explained, there are multiple definitions for some types) and do custom binding for them(I used external binding with a *-bindings.xml file). Be careful with enums as they were causing most of the problems(type, naming and so I had to custom map all values for each enum)

Lesson learnt: If your XSD files are shit, you will have hard time binding them